# Lambda as function parameter in Android onClicklistener

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, onclicklistener

I'm building a custom styled Snackbar message (https://github.com/Pradyuman7/ChocoBar) for my Android App (API 29) which I want to call by using 1 global function in my MainActivity. Below my global function:

```
fun showStyledSnackbarMessage(view: View, msg: String, msgAction: String, durationMs: Int,  icon: Int, action: (() -> Unit)) {

     ChocoBar.builder()
                    .setView(view)                    
                    .setText(msg)
                    .setActionText(msgAction)
                    .setDuration(durationMs)
                    .setIcon(icon)
                    .setActionClickListener { action } // the code to execute
                    .build()
                    .show()
}
```

My function takes a lambda as last parameter ('action'). Android Studio tells me that the 'action' parameter in unused. The .setActionClickListener is defined as follows:

```
public Builder setActionClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
            this.actionClickListener = listener;
            return this;
```

I'm failing to understand why my lambda is not working. When I click on the action button of the snackbar nothing happens. If I use this code without the global function the onClickListener does work.

Already tried it without a lambda with use of an anonymous class, same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to invoke your action

```
.setActionClickListener { action() }
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it but now my I get a type mismatch. Found: Unit, Required () -> Unit. This is the code I want to execute:

   `private fun visitWebsite() {
        val launchBrowser = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("www.google.com"))
                    startActivity(launchBrowser) }`

This does work without using the global function.

Comment: Putting the 'visitWebsite' function call into { } worked! Finally fixed my issue.